# Cannot create account with flutter, ErrorPlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have been stuck on this for days. All my files that are related are attached below. The problem is that I cannot sign up with email and password using flutter and firebase. It keeps giving me this error ErrorPlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null). Any Help would be appreciated.

Sorry for this being super long, I am relativley new to programming and flutter/firebase

1)This section does the mapping (Mapping.dart):

```
    `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
     import 'LoginRegisterPage.dart';
     import 'Homepage.dart';
     import 'Authentication.dart';

     class MappingPage extends StatefulWidget{
     final AuthImplementation auth;

     MappingPage(
     {
     this.auth,
     }
     );
     State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
     return _MappingPageState();
     }
     }

     enum AuthStatus{
     notSignedIn,
     signedIn,
     }

     class _MappingPageState extends State<MappingPage>{

     AuthStatus authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;

     void initState(){

     super.initState();
     widget.auth.GetCurrentUser().then((firebaseUserId)
     {
     setState(() {
     authStatus = (firebaseUserId == null) ? AuthStatus.notSignedIn : AuthStatus.signedIn;
     //If Id==null user not signed in else user signed in
     });
     }).catchError((onError){
     authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
     });
     }

     void _signedIn(){
     setState(() {
     authStatus = AuthStatus.signedIn;
     });
   }

   void _signedOut(){
   setState(() {
   authStatus = AuthStatus.notSignedIn;
   });
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   switch(authStatus){
   case AuthStatus.notSignedIn: 
   return new LoginRegisterPage(
   auth: widget.auth,
   onSignedIn: _signedIn,
   );

   case AuthStatus.signedIn: 
   return new Homepage(
   auth: widget.auth,
   onSignedOut: _signedOut,
   ); 
   }

   }
   }`
```

2)This section is for Login and registering (LoginRegisterPage.dart):

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'Authentication.dart';


class LoginRegisterPage extends StatefulWidget{

  LoginRegisterPage({
    this.auth,
    this.onSignedIn, onSignedOut,
  });
      final AuthImplementation auth;
      final VoidCallback onSignedIn;

State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
  return _LoginRegisterState();
  }

  }

enum FormType{
  login,
  register
}

  class _LoginRegisterState extends State <LoginRegisterPage>{

    final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
    FormType _formType =FormType.login;
    String _email = "";
    String _password ="";
       String _fname = "";
    String _lname ="";

    //methods
    bool validateSave(){
      final form = formKey.currentState;

      if(form.validate()){
        form.save();
        return true;
      }
      else{
        return false;
      }
    }

    void validateSubmit() async{
      if(validateSave()){
        try{
          if(_formType == FormType.login){
            String userId = await widget.auth.SignIn(_email, _password);
            print("login userId" + userId);
          }
          else{
            String userId = await widget.auth.SignUp(_email, _password);
            print("register userId" + userId);
          }
          widget.onSignedIn();
        }
        catch(e){
          print("Error" + e.toString());
        }
      }
    }


    void moveReg(){

      formKey.currentState.reset();

      setState(() {
        _formType = FormType.register;
      });

    }

    void moveLogin(){

      formKey.currentState.reset();

      setState(() {
        _formType = FormType.login;
      });

    }

    //Designs
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("URBAN ESTATE"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: new Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: new Form(

         key: formKey,

         child: Column(

           crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

           children: createInputs() + createButtons(),           
         ),

        ),

      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> createInputs(){
   if(_formType == FormType.login){
      return[
      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
      logo(),
      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),

      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Email"
        ),

        validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter a valid email": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _email = value;
        },

      ),

      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),

      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Password"
        ),

         validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter a valid password": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _password = value;
        },

      ),

      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),

    ];
   }
   else if(_formType == FormType.register){
      return[
      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),

      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "First Name"
        ),

         validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "This is a required field": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _fname = value;

        },
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Last Name"
        ),
         validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "This is a required field": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _lname = value;

        },
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Email"
        ),

        validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter a valid email": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _email = value;
        },

      ),

      SizedBox(height: 10.0,),

      new TextFormField(
        decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Password"
        ),
        obscureText: true,
         validator: (value){
          return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter a valid password": null;
        },

        onSaved: (value){
          return _email = value;
        },
      ),

      SizedBox(height: 20.0,),

    ];
   }
  } 

  Widget logo(){

    return new Hero(

      tag: "hero",

      child: new CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 110.0,
        child: Image.asset("assets/Logo1.png"),
      ),
    );

  } 

   List<Widget> createButtons(){
     if(_formType == FormType.login){
           return[
      new RaisedButton(
        onPressed: validateSubmit,
        child: new Text("Login", style: new TextStyle(fontSize:20.0,) ),
        textColor: Colors.black,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),

      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: () => moveReg(),
        child: new Text("Register", style: new TextStyle(fontSize:18.0, ) ),
        textColor: Colors.black,
      )

    ];
     }
     else if(_formType == FormType.register){
           return[
      new RaisedButton(
        onPressed: validateSubmit,
        child: new Text("Create Account", style: new TextStyle(fontSize:20.0,) ),
        textColor: Colors.black,
        color: Colors.amber,
      ),

      new FlatButton(
        onPressed: moveLogin,
        child: new Text("Already have an account? Login again", style: new TextStyle(fontSize:18.0, ) ),
        textColor: Colors.black,
      )

    ];
     }
  } 
}`
```

3) This section is for authentication (Authentication.dart):

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

abstract class AuthImplementation {
  Future<String> SignIn(String email, String password);
  Future<String> SignUp(String email, String password);
  Future<String> GetCurrentUser();
  Future<void> SignOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthImplementation{
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<String> SignIn(String email, String password) async
  {
    FirebaseUser user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)).user;
    return user.uid;
  }

  Future<String> SignUp(String email, String password) async
  {
    AuthResult rawUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    FirebaseUser user = (rawUser).user;
    return user != null ? user.uid : null;
  }

  Future<String> GetCurrentUser()async{
    FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    return user != null ? user.uid : null;
  }

    Future<void> SignOut() async{
      _firebaseAuth.signOut();
    }
}`
```

4) This is what I get on console:

```
`Restarted application in 1,528ms.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5035): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5035): requestCursorAnchorInfo on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5035): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5035): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(Unknown Source)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.2.0:256)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.handleCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:361)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebaseauth.FirebaseAuthPlugin.onMethodCall(FirebaseAuthPlugin.java:143)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:226)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:631)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth( 5035):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
I/flutter ( 5035): ErrorPlatformException(error, Given String is empty or null, null)`
```

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the amount of code you've shared is way too big. The idea is that **you** try to isolate the problem, so that we can help you with the minimal code. While someone may be able to spot the problems in the hundreds of lines you've shared now, the changes that we'll be able to spot it in (at most) a dozen of lines is much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you're passing `null` or an empty string to:

```
_firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

Which in turn means that you're passing `null` or an empty string to:

```
Future<String> SignUp(String email, String password) async
```

Following the call stack further up, means that the `null`/empty string comes from:

```
String userId = await widget.auth.SignUp(_email, _password)
```

The only place where you set `_email` is in these methods:

```
onSaved: (value){
  return _email = value;
},
```

If I then scan all these methods, it seems you're never setting `_password` in the same way. In fact, I think this may be your problem:

```
  new TextFormField(
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Password"
    ),
    obscureText: true,
     validator: (value){
      return value.isEmpty ? "Please enter a valid password": null;
    },

    onSaved: (value){
      return _email = value; // Should probably assign to _password
    },
  ),
```

---

This is a type of problem that is very common, and I tend to call it copy/paste/forgot-to-modify. It is usually quite difficult to spot, because your mind tends to see the code as you intend it to be, not as you've actually written is.

The best steps to debug this yourself, and reduce the days of searching to a more reasonable amount are:

1. Put a breakpoint on the call that raises the error, and check which of the values is `null` or empty. In this case that would've pointed to password in the call to `_firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);`.
2. Follow the trail of where and when `password` gets its value, and possibly where it loses its value. In this case that would've gotten you to the other lines I give above.
3. Put a breakpoint on each, and check the values. Are they what you expect them to be? If so, step into the code, and see where it stops doing what you expect it to do. If it doesn't have the correct value, keep going further up the call stack until it does; and then step into the code from there.

I've essentially done the same above to find the problem. But if you do this yourself, you'll have the advantage of being able to use the debugger, and can save yourself some time.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! I cannot believe I was stuck on this for such a silly reason. Thank you so much for the link that you commented out about the minimal stack codes as well, I found it very useful as well.